# express js error : "express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What is the right way to set path?

in my app i this code for i use set path for sending file.

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){//get,put,post,delete   
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
});
```

but it give this error:

```
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead server.js:22:6
```

can some to point what is the error here.please

Comment: replace `res.sendfile` with `res.sendFile`

Comment: see [this issue](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2276).`sendfile` is alias for `sendFile`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Change this

```
 app.get('/',function(req, res){//get,put,post,delete   
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
    });
```

to this and this should work.

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){//get,put,post,delete   
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
    });
```

In new versions `sendfile` has been deprecated. Change `sendfile` to `sendFile`.

Comment: The two snippets are identical. How is the proposed solution supposed to work?

Comment: Ha ha... You should check the syntax... sendfile vs sendFile

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer : replace res.sendfile with res.sendFile .i will give you a example with code :

```
app.get("/" ,function(req,resp){
resp.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html")})
```

```
<p>replace with this</p>

app.get("/" ,function(req,resp){
resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this working example:

```
router.get('/iso', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile('public/isofinder.html');
});
```

This is not so easily translated into the method call sendFile.

```
router.get('/iso', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/../public/isofinder.html');
});
```

This variation gives a 403 error (Forbidden).
In this case only this solution will work:

```
router.get('/iso', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('[absolute_path_to_source]/public/isofinder.html');
});
```