# express js error : “express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead”

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('public/index.html');
}); 

app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Which is giving me the error:

> express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead

So, as suggested in this similar thread ([express js error : "express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202150/express-js-error-express-deprecated-res-sendfile-use-res-sendfile-instead)) I tried renaming the `sendfile` to `sendFile` but it gives me another error:

> TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
>      at ServerResponse.sendFile (/Users/nacho4d/dev-enquete/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:394:11)
>      at /Users/nacho4d/dev-enquete/app.js:37:6

What should I do here? I am not sure if I should pass an absolute path (because of the next line: `app.use("/public", ...` .
I don't know understand well the meaning of *specify the root to res.sendFile* too.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I do here? I am not sure if I should pass an absolute path (because of the next line: `app.use("/public", ...` .

I can't claim to be very familiar with express, but I doubt that the path you have to pass to `sendFile` has anything to do with the routing. Most likely you just have to pass an absolute path to a file in the filesystem.

> I don't know understand well the meaning of specify the root to res.sendFile too.

If you look at the [**documentation**](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile), you can see that `sendFile` accepts an options object as second argument. `root` is one one of the options:

> root: Root directory for relative filenames.

It also has an example that shows how to use the options (including `root`).

If you pass a relative file path, express doesn't seem know where to start looking for the file (the directory where the file is located? the directory from where the server was started?), hence it wants you to tell it.

Comment: Thanks! doing: `var options = { root: __dirname };` `res.sendFile('public/index.html', options);` solved the problem!